# Why does this Pandas series where function not return any values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am using the Pandas library within Python and having some trouble getting expected results from filtering a specific series within a Dataframe:

```
csdf[0].unique()
```

returns:

```
array(['GWA_BTC', 'GWA_ETH', 'GWA_LTC', 'GWA_XLM', 'GWA_XRP',
       'MWA_BTC_CNY', 'MWA_BTC_EUR', 'MWA_BTC_GBP', 'MWA_BTC_JPY',
       'MWA_BTC_USD', 'MWA_ETH_CNY', 'MWA_ETH_EUR', 'MWA_ETH_GBP',
       'MWA_ETH_JPY', 'MWA_ETH_USD', 'MWA_LTC_CNY', 'MWA_LTC_EUR',
       'MWA_LTC_GBP', 'MWA_LTC_JPY', 'MWA_LTC_USD', 'MWA_XLM_CNY',
       'MWA_XLM_EUR', 'MWA_XLM_USD', 'MWA_XRP_CNY', 'MWA_XRP_EUR',
       'MWA_XRP_GBP', 'MWA_XRP_JPY', 'MWA_XRP_USD'], dtype=object)
```

But when I do this:

```
csdf[0].where(lambda x: x[0:3] == 'GWA').dropna()
```

I get:

```
Series([], Name: 0, dtype: object)
```

I am trying to get all values in the series that begin with "GWA."

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
csdf[0].where(csdf[0].str[0:3] == 'GWA').dropna()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) funtion on the series.

```
filtered = csdf[csdf[0].str.strartswith("GWA", na=False)]
```

Comment: `csdf[~csdf[0].str.strartswith("GWA", na=False)]`